# How do you open a notepad++ python file in windows powershell?

Tags: python

I am currently learning python through the book Learn Python the Hard Way by Zed Shaw. I learned the functions of windows powershell now im moving onto the other lessons. (on lesson 1)

As silly as it sounds i am having trouble opening a saved python notepad++ file in windows powershell. I am using the command:

```
python ex1.py
```

The file is **saved to my desktop** along with python and notepad++. The file is a saved notepad++ file and it is supposed to run in powershell and print what i wrote ("hello world"). Instead I get this error message:

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included. verify if the path is correct and try again.
```

So in the book when Zed Shaw does it it runs the program in powershell. Maybe my path is off?

Comment: This has nothing to do with powershell or notepad++.. Basically you are not able to execute your python code.. Wherever and however you installed python / expect it to run, is what needs to be checked.

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't recognize "python" as a valid command (based on the error message). You need to fix your path.

1. Find where your python program is installed
2. Add it to your system path
3. Refresh your shell

Answer (score 1):

Enter the path explicitly..

c:\Python27\python.exe  foo.py

(Do it wade's way it's nicer in the long run).